# Como posso enviar informações ao PayPal API PHP

Tags: php, api, pagamento-online

Bom o que pretendo é fazer o seguinte, primeiramente, como posso enviar informações ao PayPal, através do meu arquivo PHP do valor da compra.

Ou seja, o comprador seleciona o numero de itens e depois clica em Comprar, como poderei fazer com que o paypal receba o valor da compra. Ou seja se o comprador no site selecionou itens no valor de 25€, como posso fazer para passar esse valor para o PayPal, os 25€ e enviar uma referência de pagamento para mais tarde identificar o usuário que pagou.

Comment: Você já estudou a API do PayPal (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/), ou tentou usar o SDK PHP deles (http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/)? Tem alguma dúvida específica?

Comment: Cara, recomendo você dar uma estudada na API deles. Paypal tem uma documentação bem completa (maior que Pagseguro ou MOIP), então você não deve encontrar problema. A URL para te ajudar é essa:(https://www.paypal-brasil.com.br/desenvolvedores/tutorial/express-checkout-pagamentos-recorrentes/)

Comment: Estive vendo, o comprador precisa de ter conta também no sandbox paypal para poder comprar? É que eu tive a ver que o PayPal e o Sandbox PayPal são "sites" diferentes com diferentes caracteristicas. Ou seja tive q voltar a criar uma conta no sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

@Gonçalo,  O Sandbox é o ambiente de teste do Paypal. Você precisará de criar as credenciais para teste(desenvolvimento) e posteriormente para produção.
Você cria lá o usuário de teste no sandbox que você quiser pra testar. O Sandbox é um ambiente de teste para o seu desenvolvimento, quanto estiver tudo funcionando corretamente aí passa pra produção.

https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/

Comment: Mas tenho que obrigatoriamente criar uma conta la? Para poder ter esta funçao?